# How can I stop Loggly from printing to stdout (or stderr) and just sending the logs to the cloud?

Tags: node.js, winston, loggly

We're using Loggly for logging and generally very happy with it, but having upgraded to the Winston methodology I'm now finding that all my logging is not just going to the Loggly server but also being `console.log`ed out to stdout (or stderr, whichever that is).

There's not a [whole lot to the documentation](https://www.loggly.com/docs/nodejs-logs/), and I'm not seeing a way to shut this up. The whole *point of this exercise is I don't want to keep all these logs on my local machine, which is where they will wind up if they're heading to the console.

I tried deleting the Console object from the winston.transports object, but that hasn't done anything.

I'm kind of out of ideas.

Comment: Please post the code you are using to log information to Loggly.

Comment: I added a link to their tutorial. It's 4 lines of code where the only thing I'm changing is my Loggly key.  What good is that going to do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If removing default Console transport doesn't work, you can always create your own logger instance and use it.

```
var winston  = require('winston');
require('winston-loggly');

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Loggly)({
      inputToken: "TOKEN",
      subdomain: "SUBDOMAIN",
      tags: ["Winston-NodeJS"],
      json:true
    })
  ]
});

module.exports = logger;
```

You can find more information in winston documentation. Section [Using the Default Logger](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#using-the-default-logger) shows you the way to remove default console transport. The [Instantiating your own logger](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#instantiating-your-own-logger) section has information about creating a custom logger.

Comment: Nice! that works perfectly. May I ask where you found the documentation to wrap the new call the way you did? Also, when you talk about "removing default Console" is that something you can point me to? Cause that's precisely what I just spent 2 hours trying to do.